# Is there is any way to get a size information (MB,GB) from a magnet link or a complex string in Flutter / Dart using RegEx?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am working on a personal project , where I want to get the file size information from a magnet link.

Problem:
I wanna get **7.6GB** from this string below.

```
0-%20Giri%20(2004)%5bTamil%201080p%20HD%20AVC%20-%20x264%20-%207.6GB%5d.mkv&tr=http%3a%2f%2fbt4
```

I am actually new to Regex btw.

Any kind help is appreciated.(i have googled for solution , no luck)

**Edit:**
Thanks to  Vishal Singh & Stackoverflow.

Here's the working code I have tried in dartpad♥️ , incase someone searching for answers in dart.

```
void main() {
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?(GB|MB|gb|mb)");
  String str =Uri.decodeComponent(
      "0-%20Giri%20(2004)%5bTamil%201080p%20HD%20AVC%20-%20x264%20-%207.6GB%5d.mkv&tr=http%3a%2f%2fbt4");
  String match = exp.stringMatch(str);

  print(match);
}
```

Output:
 `7.6GB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex: `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(GB|MB|gb|mb)`

I didn't realize that this was a flutter/dart question and already developed a python solution. So I am posting the python solution.

```
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

magnet = "0-%20Giri%20(2004)%5bTamil%201080p%20HD%20AVC%20-%20x264%20-%207.6GB%5d.mkv&tr=http%3a%2f%2fbt4"

size = re.search(r"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(GB|MB|gb|mb)", unquote(magnet)).group()

print(size)
```

**Output:**
`7.6GB`

Comment: Thanks for your example in python. I will try to do the same in dart. Will update the post , when it's working. But ,I tried few like this before. Dart is still new to me. So, it would be great if someone suggest me the equivalent  code for dart.